# How do I draw a rectangle with OpenGL ES 2.0 in iOS ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I have been learning and using Objective-C and cocos2d (iOS game-engine) for a couple of years now and so I decided to start with OpenGL ES for iOS devices. I have started reading a book that covers this topic, however with little background in this area I have to admit that I am a little lost. I am a really practical person and I only learn by doing things myself. The book does give some nice examples, but unfortunately mostly covers triangular shapes.

**So, I have a couple of questions regarding OpenGL:**

- Do vertices really need to be declared in a counter-clockwise order to prevent culling ?
- Does OpenGL really draw all shapes based on triangles ?
- If so, how would I draw a rectangle ?

I would really appreciate it if somebody could write a quick vertex array sample of how to achieve to draw a rect on the screen. No need for the buffers or anything, really just the vertices of the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGl ES 2.0 supports the following rendering types: GL_POINTS, GL_LINE_STRIP, GL_LINE_LOOP, GL_LINES, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, and GL_TRIANGLES.

If you ignore the ones for drawing points and lines you can choose between [triangle strips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip), [triangle fans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_fan) and simple triangles. To draw a rectangle you can easily use two triangles.

To specify the ordering for face culling you can use [glFrontFace](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml). However its common practise (as far as i know) to use counter clockwise ordering.

If you have problems finding good opengl es 2.0 tutorials for ios you should maybe look for some tutorials on some plattforms. WebGL and Android are also using opengl es 2.0 and (except the syntax) the code will look nearly identical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what you are saying is, that shapes really do consist of triangles, right ? So a rectangle HAS TO consist of two triangles, if I understand correctly. I did not quite get your point  regarding counter-clockwise ordering. I do not need to specify the culling mode if I order them counter-clockwise, right ? Do you have any good references to good tutorials ? :)

Comment: Standard OpenGL (not ES) had also support for quads. However this got removed in OpenGL 3.1. So yes.. every shape has to consist out of triangles. If you use counter-clockwise ordering you don't have to change anything (this is the default value of `glFrontFace`). I used these tutorials some time ago for webgl: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217

Comment: thanks I checked it out. As far as I understand, OpenGL draws the triangles internally, doesn't it ? Because a square in this tutorial is specified by its four corner points anyway. So OpenGL goes over the array and connects these triangles itself. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Using four coordinates to render the square works because a triangle strip is used (see my link in the answer)